# What's wrong in this solution to number of ways to generate change (Top Down)?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

The famous [coin change problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/coin-change) from hacker rank. It asks to compute a total number of ways to make a change for N using coins of given denominations.

For example, there are 5 ways to make a change for 10 using coins of denominations 2, 3, 4 and 5. They should be: `{2,2,2,2,2}, {2,2,3,3}, {2,2,6}, {2,3,5} and {5,5}`

I am unable to figure out a bug in my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long getWays(int n, long c[], int m)

{
    long dp[m + 1][n + 1];

for (long i = 0; i < m + 1; i++)
{
    dp[i][0] = 1;
}

for (long k = 1; k < m + 1; k++)
{
    for (long j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
    {
        dp[k][j] = 0;
        if (c[k - 1] <= j)
        {
            dp[k][j] = dp[k - 1][j] + dp[k][j - c[k - 1]];
        }
        else
        {
            dp[k][j] = dp[k - 1][j];
        }
            cout<<dp[k][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return dp[m][n];
}

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    long arr[] = {2, 5, 3, 6};
    int m=4;
    cout << getWays(n, arr, m) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(*c)` doesn't do what you think it does. This should be explained in every C++ textbook, but, unfortunately, not on hackerrank, or any other pointless hacking/coding site. See your C++ textbook for the correct explanation of what `sizeof` means. Furthermore, `int c[]` as a function parameter is not an array, and `sizeof` does not give you the number of values in this array. Again, something that's also explained in every C++ textbook. If you are trying to learn C++, you will learn a lot more from a textbook, than from hackerrank.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look into it!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've corrected the syntax now. The code is still not giving the desired answer.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the motivation!
I've learned the debugger and have corrected my code :D @SamVarshavchik

Comment: `long dp[m + 1][n + 1];` -- This is not valid C++ syntax.  Arrays in C++ must be declared by using a constant to determine the number of variables, not a runtime value.  That should be `std::vector<std::vector<long>> dp(m+1, std::vector<long>(n+1));`.  Second, that `bits` header is non-standard.  Use the proper `#include` files, not that one.

Answer (score -1):

Corrected code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long getWays(int n, long c[], int m)
{
long dp[m + 1][n + 1];

for (long i = 0; i < m + 1; i++)
{
    dp[i][0] = 1;
}

 for (long i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
{
    dp[0][i] = 0;
}

for (long k = 1; k < m + 1; k++)
{
    for (long j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
    {
        if (c[k - 1] <= j)
        {
            dp[k][j] = dp[k - 1][j] + dp[k][j - c[k - 1]];
        }
        else
        {
            dp[k][j] = dp[k - 1][j];
        }

    }
}
return dp[m][n];
}

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    long arr[] = {2, 5, 3, 6};
    int m=4;
    cout << getWays(n, arr, m) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See my comments in the main section.  That code fails to compile due to using non-standard syntax.  If I took that code and attempted to compile it with Visual Studio, for example, the compilation will fail.